# Compare two objects and add them in a Set

Tags: java

I have two sets, I need to compare them using some entity inside the set.

```
Set<Node> appNodes = Sets.newHashSet(PropertyUtils.getInstance().getListOfAppNodes());
Set<Node> dataNodes = Sets.newHashSet(PropertyUtils.getInstance().getListOfDataNodes());
Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<>();
```

**Node POJO**

```
public class Node {
  String hostName;
  String ip;
  String userName;
  String passWord;

  public String getHostName() {
    return hostName;
  }

  public void setHostName(String hostName) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
  }

  public String getIp() {
    return ip;
  }

  public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
  }

  public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
  }

  public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
  }

  public String getPassWord() {
    return passWord;
  }

  public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
    this.passWord = passWord;
  }
}
```

I need to compare the two sets using ip and add them in nodes Set.

```
nodes.addAll(appNodes);
nodes.addAll(dataNodes);
```

When trying to doi it like in the above code, I get all the data from appnode set and datanode set,
but I want to compare the ip in appnode set and datanode set, if they aren't the same I only need to add them in the new set.

Comment: you need to implement the **equals** method to compare to object of same class. Just add  **equals** method in *Node* class

Comment: you can also implement the comparable interface in the *Node* class

Comment: Can you Please explain with sample code as i m new to comparator

Comment: You need to implement `equals()` ***and*** `hashCode()` for your objects.

Comment: _"Can you Please explain with sample code"_ -- This code is easily findable on the web.  Comparing objects is a question that gets asked several times a day here.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/780/comparable-and-comparator-in-java-example please refer the link